# Switch statement eclipse error: case expressions must be constant expressions

Tags: java, eclipse, switch-statement

I wrote a program that would output a flower based off the color I will input. In the switch statement, I keep seeing an error stating that the "case expressions must be constant expressions." I don't see where I am doing it wrong. I'm also having an issue of printing out the plural tense of the flower (if the user would input 2 or higher).

Here's the code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int quantity;
    String color;
    String flowerType = "";
    char extra;

    System.out.print("Please enter a color: ");
    color = input.next();
    System.out.print("Please enter the quantity: ");
    quantity = input.nextInt();

    String red = "red";
    String blue = "blue";
    String yellow = "yellow";
    String purple = "purple";
    String white = "white";

    switch(color){
    case red:
        flowerType = "rose";
        break;
    case blue:
        flowerType = "iris";
        break;
    case yellow:
        flowerType = "daffodil";
        break;
    case purple:
        flowerType = "sage";
        break;
    case white:
        flowerType = "dogwood";
        break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid color.");
    }
    switch(quantity){
    case 1:
        break;
    default:
        extra = 's';
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("You have " + quantity + flowerType + extra + ".");
}
```

}

Comment: You cannot use variables in case statements. They must be **constants**.

Answer (score 4):

Mark the variables `red`, `purple`, etc, as final.

```
final String red = "red";
final String blue = "blue";
final String yellow = "yellow";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use string literals for the color name instead of using variables.

```
switch(color) {
case "red":
     ...
case "blue":
     ...
... //other cases also with ""
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Any statement in a switch must be a **compile-time constant**, which means it must be a constant that is a literal or is assignet by a literal. Literals are all values written directly into code. Constants are values that can't change after beeing assigned, which means any final value is a constant. The static modifier is highly advised for mathematical constants (and to reduce space used by instances).

```
final String red = "red";
case red:
     ... //insert code here
     break;
```

and

```
case "red":
     ... //insert code here
     break;
```

will both work.

On the other side functions returning a string won't work:

```
static final String s = new String("abc");
final String s = new String("abcd");
```

won't work, because the method can't be executed at compiletime.

Answer (score 0):

The standard value for a char is shown as a rectancle box, use a string if you want to have an empty character as standard value. Also use if's for conditions and not switches.

```
package pointless;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SO {
    static final String red = "red";
    static final String blue = "blue";
    static final String yellow = "yellow";
    static final String purple = "purple";
    static final String white = "white";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int quantity;
        String color;
        String flowerType = "";
        String extra = ""; //using a string is better cause it can be empty, a char can't be empty

        System.out.print("Please enter a color: ");
        color = input.next();
        System.out.print("Please enter the quantity: ");
        quantity = input.nextInt();

        switch(color){
            case red:
                flowerType = "rose";
                break;
            case blue:
                flowerType = "iris";
                break;
            case yellow:
                flowerType = "daffodil";
                break;
            case purple:
                flowerType = "sage";
                break;
            case white:
                flowerType = "dogwood";
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid color.");
        }
        if(quantity>1) { // use a if for checking conditions like quantity>1
            extra="s";
        }
        System.out.println("You have " + quantity+ " " + flowerType + extra + ".");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is something the code should look like :
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

```
    int quantity;
    String color;
    String flowerType = "";
    char extra;

    System.out.print("Please enter a color: ");
    color = input.next();
    System.out.print("Please enter the quantity: ");
    quantity = input.nextInt();

    final String  red = "red";
    final String blue = "blue";
    final String yellow = "yellow";
    final String purple = "purple";
    final String white = "white";

    switch(color){
    case red:
        flowerType = "rose";
        break; 
    case blue:
        flowerType = "iris";
        break; 
    case yellow:
        flowerType = "daffodil";
        break; 
    case purple:
        flowerType = "sage";
        break; 
    case white:
        flowerType = "dogwood";
        break; 
        default: 
            System.out.println("Invalid color.");
    } 
    switch(quantity){
    case 1: 
        System.out.println("You have " + quantity + flowerType+".");
        break; 
    default: 
        extra = 's';
        System.out.println("You have " + quantity + flowerType + extra + ".");
        break; 
    } 

}
```

Comment: The last 2 lines are really bad style, copying code will always lead to bugs, because if you change one line it's easy forget changing the other and it's fiddly to change every line by hand. I think the original way of OP to print was better.

Comment: true. thats why the break is used there. thanks @HopefullyHelpful